# In AzureML, start_logging will start asynchronous execution or synchronous execution?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

It was written in the Microsoft AzureML documentation, "A run represents a single trial of an experiment. Runs are used to monitor the asynchronous execution of a trial" and A Run object is also created when you submit or start_logging with the Experiment class."

Related to `start_logging`, as far as I know, when we have simply started the run by executing this `start logging` method. We have to stop, or complete by `complete` method when the run is completed. This is because  `start_logging` is a synchronized way of creating an experiment. However, Run object created from `start_logging` is to monitor the asynchronous execution of a trial.

Can anyone clarify whether `start_logging` will start asynchronous execution or synchronous execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**start_logging** will be considered as **asynchronous** execution as this generates the multiple interactive run sessions. In a specific experiment, there is a chance of multiple interactive sessions, that work parallelly and there will be no scenario to be followed in sequential.

The individual operation can be performed and recognized based on the parameters like **args**  and **kwargs**.

When the start_logging is called, then an interactive run like **jupyter notebook** was created. The complete metrics and components which are created when the start_logging was called will be utilized. When the output directory was mentioned for each interactive run, based on the args value, the output folder will be called seamlessly.

The following code block will help to define the operation of start_logging

```
experiment = Experiment(your_workspace, "your_experiment_name")
   run = experiment.start_logging(outputs=None, snapshot_directory=".", display_name="test")
   ...
   run.log_metric("Accuracy_Value", accuracy)
   run.complete()
```

the below code block will be defining the basic syntax of start_logging

```
start_logging(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you!. In your example (the code),  experiment.start_logging(outputs=None, snapshot_directory=".", display_name="test") creates one interactive run? is there any way, the code creates multiple interactive run sessions in your example (code)

Comment: As it is asynchronous, it can with run multiple sessions.